# Dpkg error processing for installing packages

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, repository

I want to install any packages but when I use `apt-get install` I have the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
htop is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up w3af (1.2-bt2) ...
tar: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
/var/lib/dpkg/info/w3af.postinst: line 4: cd: pybloomfiltermmap-0.2.0: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/w3af/code/trunk'; please relocate
dpkg: error processing w3af (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 w3af
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I want to update it I also have problems on connecting to repositories.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

try

> sudo apt-get remove w3af

it should remove that package and then everything would be normal.

`

Comment: Thank you. After doing that when I enter `apt-get install w3af --fix-missing` There is error for installing that. Or when I am going to update system

Comment: try *sudo apt-get -f install* to correct that. else it is a broken package. BTW, you can delete that package from /var/cache/apt and do installation once again so that it is freshly downloaded.